# Eclipse code assist doesn't propose boolean java bean getter

Tags: java, eclipse

maybe this is not the best *forum* for asking this question, but I have a little problem :

I was used to hit ctrl + space to fire the eclipse code assist, and use the proposed suggestions to write getters and setters for the private members of a classe.

For a *normal* member, I can get getXXX et setXXX propositions. For **boolean** Eclipse normaly suggests isXXX and setXXX.

For some weeks now, the isXXX is not in the list anymore, but I can ask eclipse to generate it for me with the *generate getters and setters* menu.

How can I enable back the isXXX getter for boolean member code assist ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `Boolean` to `boolean`.

Comment: Ok, declaring my member as Boolean, restore the isXXX getter proposition, but it doesn't works anymore for boolean ???

Comment: `isXXX` is for `boolean`-s, `getXXX` is for `Boolean`-s.

Comment: getXXX for Boolean and isXXX seems normal to me. But I have : nothing for boolean, and isXXX for Boolean ? Strange.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Point the mouse over the variable and click on it it will show one pop up like in the image i have uploaded.

Comment: Yes, this works too, but I used to go somewhere between methods and use ctrl+space, there the popup show every methods that I can override, and also every getter and setter that can be created. I is much faster (no mouse actions) and now the isXXX getter is not in this list anymore.

Comment: Try right click -> source -> generate getter setter

Comment: Thanks, but like I said, using this method works, but it involve using the mouse, and it generates (by default) getter AND setter, using the keyboard is much faster, and used to works.